# Angular Component error in the console: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: angular

Currently I’m getting this strange error in my Chrome console. I don’t understand how to approach in solving it.

```
PractiseLayoutComponent.html:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (PractiseLayoutComponent.html:10)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:13105)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12256)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12531)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12257)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12531)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12257)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13467)
```

Probably I’ve done something wrong. Unfortunately, it is very costly to revert changes.
Anyway I definitely should get know how to cope with such a situation.
Could anyone give some advice where to dig?

There is no error from `ng serve` in the terminal.

Comment: You could probably start by posting the concerned code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into your PractiseLayoutComponent.html at line 10. There might be something missing there.